# i915 Intel Skylake: System-freeze after wake up from hibernate (suspend to disk)

Tags: debian, suspend, hibernate, i915

The problem is that very often (not always) after I supend to disk (hibernate) and try to wake up the machine using the power button, the display freezes and nothing more is happening, it just hangs at a black screen. Even the login-shells at `ALT F1-6` are in a hanging state and do not responding.

It does not matter if I use `echo disk > /sys/power/state`, `systemctl hibernate`, `hibernate-disk` (from the debian package `hibernate`) or `s2disk` (from the debian package `uswusp`) - the behaviour is always the same.

I enabled `no_console_suspend initcall_debug ignore_loglevel` in GRUB and could see that it always hangs at the same point:

[image: boot-debugginh]

If I wait a while, I get the following message:

[image]

I disabled `RC6` in GRUB (`i915.enable_rc6=0`) and it did not helped. It hangs at the same point, but this time it says `[drm] RC6 off`.

Then I read [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113551), that I should boot with `intel_pstate=no_hwp` - so I did that, but it did not help.

I also tried to boot with `nomodeset i915.modeset=0` which I removed as I can not change the resolution anymore and with `acpi=off` ([resource](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting)) which also did not help.

The very strange thing is, that with the same laptop, on `Debian 8` it work flawlessly. The problem with hibernate began when I moved to `Debian 9`. Here is my data:

```
Lenovo Thinkpad L460
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
OS: Debian 9, 4.14.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
RAM: 16GB, SWAP: 20GB

Graphics: VGA compatible controller:
Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Kernel-Module: i915

# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d12 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM (rev 21)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)

# dpkg --list | grep -i xorg
ii  xserver-xorg                         1:7.7+19                                         amd64        X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-core                    2:1.19.2-1+deb9u2                                amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-all               1:7.7+19                                         amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput          0.23.0-2                                         amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all               1:7.7+19                                         amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu            1.2.0-1+b1                                       amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati               1:7.8.0-1+b1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev             1:0.4.4-1+b5                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel             2:2.99.917+git20161206-1                         amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau           1:1.0.13-3                                       amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon            1:7.8.0-1+b1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa              1:2.3.4-1+b2                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware            1:13.2.1-1+b1                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati               1:7.8.0-1+b1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev             1:0.4.4-1+b5                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel             2:2.99.917+git20161206-1                         amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau           1:1.0.13-3                                       amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon            1:7.8.0-1+b1                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa              1:2.3.4-1+b2                                     amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware            1:13.2.1-1+b1                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver

# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
vhost_net              24576  1
vhost                  45056  1 vhost_net
tap                    24576  1 vhost_net
tun                    32768  3 vhost_net
bridge                139264  0
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
nf_log_ipv4            16384  1
nf_log_common          16384  1 nf_log_ipv4
xt_LOG                 16384  1
xt_limit               16384  1
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  1
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
xt_tcpudp              16384  29
xt_conntrack           16384  28
iptable_mangle         16384  0
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  30
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 32768  2 nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4
nf_conntrack          139264  6 nf_conntrack_ipv4,ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_i
pv4,nf_nat
libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_nat
iptable_filter         16384  1
nls_ascii              16384  1
nls_cp437              20480  1
vfat                   20480  1
fat                    65536  1 vfat
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
arc4                   16384  2
snd_soc_skl            86016  0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        65536  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_hda_ext_core       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          225280  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
iwlmvm                249856  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
mac80211              671744  1 iwlmvm
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  0
iwlwifi               192512  1 iwlmvm
kvm_intel             200704  4
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm                   589824  1 kvm_intel
i915                 1359872  3
snd_hda_core           81920  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
irqbypass              16384  3 kvm
efi_pstore             16384  0
intel_cstate           16384  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
snd_pcm                98304  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_core
thinkpad_acpi          81920  1
intel_uncore          122880  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
efivars                20480  1 efi_pstore
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
cfg80211              610304  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
drm_kms_helper        163840  1 i915
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
battery                20480  0
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
rfkill                 28672  3 thinkpad_acpi,cfg80211
evdev                  24576  15
snd                    81920  11 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
video                  40960  2 thinkpad_acpi,i915
soundcore              16384  1 snd
drm                   372736  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
wmi                    24576  1 wmi_bmof
ac                     16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
sg                     32768  0
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
button                 16384  1 i915
nbd                    36864  0
parport_pc             28672  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
sunrpc                331776  1
efivarfs               16384  1
ip_tables              24576  3 iptable_mangle,iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               36864  8 xt_LOG,iptable_mangle,ip_tables,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_limit,xt_conntrack
autofs4                40960  2
ext4                  622592  7
crc16                  16384  1 ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  102400  1 ext4
crc32c_generic         16384  0
fscrypto               28672  1 ext4
ecb                    16384  0
algif_skcipher         16384  0
af_alg                 24576  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               36864  1
dm_mod                118784  25 dm_crypt
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
sd_mod                 49152  4
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  11
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
ahci                   36864  3
aesni_intel           188416  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mmc_core              139264  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
libata                237568  2 ahci,libahci
e1000e                245760  0
rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
xhci_pci               16384  0
mfd_core               16384  1 rtsx_pci
xhci_hcd              212992  1 xhci_pci
cryptd                 24576  4 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
usbcore               249856  3 usbhid,xhci_pci,xhci_hcd
psmouse               143360  0
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
scsi_mod              221184  3 sd_mod,libata,sg
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
thermal                20480  0
```

Additional information: I use a second monitor, which I turn off (`xrandr --output DP-1 --off`) before I go to hibernate state. Also some KVMs are running when entering hibernate state. Also I installed the packages `firmware-misc-nonfree firmware-linux-nonfree intel-microcode` and the original drivers from intel, found [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/skylake-guc-6.1) and [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/skylake-dmc-1.26).

Please help me, I'm really frustrated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using a kernel similar to that try adding these to your boot codes.  They are case sensitive. I have a Dell I7-7559 Laptop.

```
acpi_osi=!Windows i915.preliminary_hw_support=1
```